# Having issues of having Bootstrap NAV TABS and Grid System working in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am having issues of having Bootstrap NAV TABS and Grid System to work in the same page. I can get one or the other to work by changing (commenting out) the bootstrap references. So I assume its my Bootstrap stylesheet or javascript link that is incorrect.

I just want both container-row-col grid system and the nav-tabs to work together

Any guidance would be awesome. Thank you

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- NAV TABS does NOT work but bootstrap does work -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    
    <!-- NAV TABS work but bootstrap grid does not work -->
    <!--
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
  -->


    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          1 of 2
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          2 of 2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          1 of 3
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          2 of 3
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          3 of 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <h3>HOME</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Menu 1</h3>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Menu 2</h3>
          <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Menu 3</h3>
          <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use 2 different versions of bootstrap, just stick to one. If you choose to use v.4.3.1, you need to change the nav-tabs portion to the new one, [found here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#tabs)

First, remove the other link to the older bootstrap and replace the javascript bundle with the one found in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)

```html
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
```

Replace this part:

```html
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

With this: (To adhere with the changes in version)

```html
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home"
          aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" role="tab" aria-controls="menu1"
          aria-selected="true">Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3" role="tab" aria-controls="menu2"
          aria-selected="false">Menu 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3" role="tab" aria-controls="menu3"
          aria-selected="false">Menu 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="menu1-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="menu2-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="menu3-tab">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the full working snippet:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        1 of 2
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        2 of 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        1 of 3
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        2 of 3
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        3 of 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home"
          aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" role="tab" aria-controls="menu1"
          aria-selected="true">Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" role="tab" aria-controls="menu2"
          aria-selected="false">Menu 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3" role="tab" aria-controls="menu3"
          aria-selected="false">Menu 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">HOME PAGE</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="menu1-tab">MENU1 PAGE</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="menu2-tab">MENU2 PAGE</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="menu3-tab">MENU3 PAGE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great detailed response !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order of the scripts on the html file, because the scripts are loaded in order, maybe this is causing the problem